# Velocity of approach which changes continuously

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

> There are two particles A and B which are moving with constant speed $v$ and $u$ such that $v$ is always directed towards B. At $t = 0$, the separation between A and B is $l$ and $u$ is perpendicular to the line joining A and B. The Velocity of B is constant i.e., it does not change its direction. Also $v>u$. Find the time when they will collide.

Here's my approach

The angle which A makes with the horizontal changes continuously from $0$ to $\theta$(let). At any time the angle which $v$ makes with horizontal will be a function of time. So $\alpha = f(t) $ where $\alpha$ lies from $0$ to $\theta$. Let time when they will collide be $t$ sec. 
So, $$\int_0^t v\cos(f(t)) dt = l$$
And
$$\int_0^t v\sin(f(t)) dt = ut$$
Now I am stuck what to do next

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea about setup but as long as you are fixated on angles and endpoints *per se* you will have trouble. What you actually want to write would seem to be the coupled equations
$$\dot x(t) = v\cos\alpha=v\frac{x-ut}{\sqrt{y^2 + (x-u t)^2}}\\
\dot y(t) = v\sin\alpha=-v\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + (x-u t)^2}}
$$
And then maybe you can solve for this. So all I have done here is substituted the definition of sine and cosine for this triangle in.

That looks complicated, though, and I wonder if it would be much easier to consider a particle with variable velocity $v(t)$ traveling toward the origin, then transform this into the desired reference frame to just get an equation for $v(t)$ which makes the transformed velocity constant.